# To hyphenate borne, or not to hyphenate borne?

Tags: punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word)

In my place of business, it is part of our style guide to hyphenate "vehicle-borne IED," but not hyphenate "foodborne."  As the editor, I am looking for some definitive guidance on when adjectives containing "borne" are hyphenated.  Any ideas?

Comment: See: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21104/hyphen-or-no-hyphen-when-modifying-an-adjective-with-a-quantity

Comment: @Gnawme: I'm voting with you. I can't see the original currently addresses OP's exact question, but we can't keep proliferating questions like this for every word-pair that could be hyphenated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that there is no [definitive guidance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf) available. Punctuation at that level is entirely a matter of local and personal style.

If your style guide doesn't have a rule for it, make up your own, if you believe that consistency is that important. You're the editor, after all.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I do:  Look the "word" up in the dictionary. If it is there hyphenate it the way you find it. If it is not there then it is by definition not a word, but a two-word, compound adjective, and I hyphenate it.

Comment: The problem with this approach is dictionaries are always playing "catch-up" with actual usage. And in the case of hyphenation, most of the popular movement is towards discarding them. If OP actually wants *foodborne* to be non-hyphenated this suggests he wants to be at the "leading edge" of usage. I don't think many dictionaries would have that one - lots of them still have *air-borne*, for example, which strikes me as positively quaint today.

Comment: On the other hand, if OP wanted to be leading-edge then she'd hyphenate as she pleased. Since she's looking for a rule she clearly would prefer to stick with established convention.

Comment: Touché! Definitely leading-edge hyphenation there! (I missed my chance to get in first, having been saddled with a noun rather than adjectival context! :)